# Using certbot to apply Let's Encrypt Certificate: Failed authorization procedure

Tags: nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I am using certbot to apply `Let's Encrypt` certificate,
my server is centos `7.2` and nginx `1.11.9`.
what does this mean below?

```
[root@test ~]# certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/www.example.com -d example.com -d www.example.com

Failed authorization procedure. example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://example.com/.well-known/acme-ch
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>", www.example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/k
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - If you lose your account credentials, you can recover through
   e-mails sent to example@example.com.
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/wGNv57IGJjHQ9wyzzALktpNaPzfnTtN3m7u3QuO4p40:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   Domain: www.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/kFJ0CSuKOdgcT2xmciB4GGNCcnUPoIbpQmA9jOII_Bk:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
 - Your account credentials have been saved in your Certbot
   configuration directory at /etc/letsencrypt. You should make a
   secure backup of this folder now. This configuration directory will
   also contain certificates and private keys obtained by Certbot so
   making regular backups of this folder is ideal.
```

I can access `example.com` and `www.example.com`,and there is a note in docs: https://certbot.eff.org/#centosrhel7-nginx

> Note:
>   To use the webroot plugin, your server must be configured to serve files from hidden directories. If /.well-known is treated specially by your webserver configuration, you might need to modify the configuration to ensure that files inside /.well-known/acme-challenge are served by the webserver.

Is that the reason?
How to modify the configuration?

Answer (score 16):

I was having this problem. I figured it out after 4 grueling hours of debugging. If your server supports both ipv4 and ipv6, make sure you have BOTH of these lines in your server configuration:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
```

The [::]: in the second line tells it to listen on ipv6. If you're missing that second line, what will happen is that when you run certbot, the LetsEncrypt server will try to access your server via ipv6. But since your application vhost isn't listening on ipv6, nginx will direct it to the `default` vhost handler if you have it enabled (since that handler DOES listen on ipv6). Since the `default` handler can't serve the required challenge file, it will give a 404.

---

If this doesn't fix your problem: in general, when debugging certbot, make sure the request isn't being handled by the `default` vhost (or any other vhost). You can check this by [adding a log directive](https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-log-files/) to the configuration file for the default vhost, running certbot, and then checking the log file you specified to see if the request from Letsencrypt shows up in there. If this isn't the problem, check if you can access the challenge file from your browser. To do this, you'll need to add the location directives that certbot adds to your application configuration file. Certbot will dump its modifications to the config file in its log file. In my experience, it doesn't actually create the challenge files in `/.well-known/acme-challenge`. It literally just hardcodes the response for that url into the config file. So recreate that and then check if you can access it from your browser.

Comment: Thanks. can't believe this was the problem.

Comment: also make sure port 80 is open

Answer (score 11):

This is a pretty common problem but fortunately should be an easy fix. Let's Encrypt must be able to read from the .well-known directory to verify that your server actually hosts the domain you want a certificate for.

First, make sure you have a .well-known directory in your website root. Set your permissions so that it is readable from the outside; 775 should be perfect.

Then, add this snippet to your virtual host file in Nginx:

```
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
```

This will allow any requests to the .well-known directory we just created. Now, try requesting a cert again, and see if it works.

Comment: Certbot creates and handles the `.well-known` directory by itself, there is no need to create it manually.

Comment: Also, with the `.well-known` it's important to make sure nginx is not blocking all "dot" files in a conf file somewhere, as that can block the http-01 challenge response

Answer (score 2):

@user234683 answer helped me a alot.

In my case the problem was with the cloudflare. Somehow cloudflare is not redirecting certbots request to my servers. When I opened `/.well-known/acme-challenge` on browser it clearly mentioned a cloudflare error.
So here what I did, I disabled ssl on cloudflare then renewed certificate on my server - everything finished in two minutes.

Hope it helps someone out there.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

then run
Let's Encrypt commands, after this run

```
sudo service nginx restart all
```

Comment: For me, I had to restart apache2. Seems like there was junk stuck in the cache. Restarting the apache2 service helped me. Thanks!